# Does mini-batch gradient descent nullify the effect of stratification on the training data set?

Tags: neural-network, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

In data pre-processing, [stratified shuffle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) is used to ensure that the distribution of the original dataset is reflected in the training, test and validation dataset.

Mini-batch gradient descent uses [random shuffling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/why-should-we-shuffle-data-while-training-a-neural-network) to ensure randomness in the mini-batches.

My doubt is- Why should we implement stratified shuffle on our dataset if it is going to be shuffled in a random manner later during training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't, the workflow when training a model is like that:

1. Create 10 evenly distributed splits from the dataset using stratified shuffle
2. train set = 8 splits;
   validation set = 1 split;
   test set = 1 split
3. Shuffle the train set and the validation set and create minibatches from them
4. Train for one epoch using the batches
5. Repeat from step 3 until all epochs are over
6. Evaluate the model using the test set

If we skip the stratified shuffling in step 1 the classes of the train set, validation set and test set wont be evenly distributed.

If we skip the shuffling before each epoch in step 3 the mini-batches in each epoch will be the same.

The proportions of the train set, validation set and test set can of course vary.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, based on your answer I deduce that stratification is done mainly to keep the distribution intact in validation as well as test dataset. It does not cause issues during training.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't cause issues during training. It's only done so the train set, validation set and test set are similary distributed.

Comment: All stratified StratifiedShuffleSplit does is shuffle the data randomly, then create x splits which have the same class distributions. So if your dataset has 80% rows from class A and 20% rows from class B it makes sure each of the x splits also has 80% rows from class A and 20% rows from class B.